# Accessing String in AsyncTask from outer class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have my Main Activity and in that Activity I have a private AsyncTask class. In my public AsyncTask class, there is a String I will need access that my MainActivity after my AsyncTask has finished.

How would I be able to access the String in my Async Task class from my Main Activity?

EDIT: I'm calling AsyncTask in the OnCreate of my Activity

Async Task class(Near bottom is the String I need):

```
public class getLikes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    JSONObject obj = null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            String jsonUser = fb.request("5027904559");

            obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);


        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     //I need to use this String elsewhere in my MainActivity
        String name = obj.optString("likes");




    }

}
```

Here is where I need to use the string(if it matters)

```
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1), true, names));
```

Comment: Try using a global variable for the string you need.

Comment: put a name variable in your main class and access it from your asynctask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a constructor where you hand in an Observer like this one:

```
interface TaskCompletionObserver {
    taskCompleted(Object result)
}
```

The constructor would look like this:

```
public GetLikes(TaskCompletionObserver observer){
    super();
    this.mObserver = observer;
}
```

Then in the onPosteExecute simply call:

```
mObserver.taskCompleted(whatever_you_want_to_pass);
```

Your activity should then implement TaskCompletionObserver and in the implementation of taskCompleted you can do what you need to do (e.g. update the UI)

You could then lateron extend your implementation to a fully fedged [observer patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

It's good design and keeps your code maintainable and flexible.

Comment: I think you meant to declare the constructor as follows: `public getLikes(TaskCompletionObserver observer)`.  I don't believe AsyncTask has a constructor that takes a Context instance.

Comment: I think it's a bit overkill, from an inner class you can access variables from outer class. This system could be used if you need to know when the value is ready

Comment: I think in 90% all cases it pays off to not make async task inner classes of activities. The other 10% are code-demos. When developing good software you should always try to keep your code maintainable. And as you can see it's just a few lines of code.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno - maybe. But having the AsyncTask uncoupled from the activity that uses it is often a better design. It's easier to write (unit) tests for both the getLikes class and the Activity class. Easier re-usabliity, easier to refactor later on, etc...

Comment: Well, an Asynctask is strongly related to an Activity (in most cases, don't read it wrong) so create the class outside the Activity class doesn't make so much sense (there are could be case where it's better to put it outside but i'm not talking about it). Personally i think in this specific case all this could be avoided and put the UI update in the onPostExecute since he just add the elements in a navdrawer and i don't think he need this value in another place (but i can't be sure about it). (P.S the param in your constructor should be TaskCompletionObserver not IObserver)

Comment: And you could avoid to write super() too since it's always invoked by default in this case